# Cant edit base URL in new stores for multistore

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, multisite

I've added new websites, stores and store views. Now I need to edit the base URLs for each store but when I try to click them to change them in the back end admin panel those fields are locked.

Any ideas? Is there a php bin/magento command I need to run to get the base_config_urls tables to get added in the database or something?

[image: Can't edit any BASE URLs]